# How to remove @XmlElementRefs and replace them with java properties

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

I have the following class

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "SegmentFilter")
public class SegmentFilter {

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name = "StopRange", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "OverlapRange", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "DateRange", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "DurationRange", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "EmployeeSelector", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "SegmentCode", type = JAXBElement.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name = "StartRange", type = JAXBElement.class)
    })
    @XmlMixed
    protected List<Serializable> content;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "IncludeDetailSegments")
    protected Boolean includeDetailSegments;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "IncludeGeneralSegments")
    protected Boolean includeGeneralSegments;

    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

    public boolean isIncludeDetailSegments() {
        if (includeDetailSegments == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return includeDetailSegments;
        }
    }

    public void setIncludeDetailSegments(Boolean value) {
        this.includeDetailSegments = value;
    }

    public boolean isIncludeGeneralSegments() {
        if (includeGeneralSegments == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return includeGeneralSegments;
        }
    }

    public void setIncludeGeneralSegments(Boolean value) {
        this.includeGeneralSegments = value;
    }

}
```

Can someone please help me replace the ref with actual Java code like:

```java
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "SegmentFilter")
public class SegmentFilter {

    public DateTimeRangeType StopRange;
    public DateTimeRangeType StartRange;

    //and so on with getters and setters

    @XmlAttribute(name = "IncludeDetailSegments")
    protected Boolean includeDetailSegments;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "IncludeGeneralSegments")
    protected Boolean includeGeneralSegments;

    public List<Serializable> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Serializable>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }

    public boolean isIncludeDetailSegments() {
        if (includeDetailSegments == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return includeDetailSegments;
        }
    }

    public void setIncludeDetailSegments(Boolean value) {
        this.includeDetailSegments = value;
    }

    public boolean isIncludeGeneralSegments() {
        if (includeGeneralSegments == null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return includeGeneralSegments;
        }
    }

    public void setIncludeGeneralSegments(Boolean value) {
        this.includeGeneralSegments = value;
    }

}
```

I was able to do if I remove type with actual XSD of complex object, for example DateTimeRangeType in this case. I am using Eclipse to generate JAXB classes. This is the XSD below. In earlier cases when there was no type and all elements were defined in the main parent class it was able to get the XSD format, but does not seem to be working in this case where type is pointing to a complex type of xsd

```xml
<xs:element name="SegmentFilter">
 <xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>
    SegmentFilter is a root-level element used 
 in a SegmentFilter request.
  </xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
 <xs:complexType mixed="true">
<xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="EmployeeSelector" 
type="EmployeeSelectorType" minOccurs="0" />
  
    <xs:element name="DateRange" 
type="DateRangeType"/>
    <xs:element name="DurationRange" 
type="FromToTimeRangeType"/>
    <xs:element name="SegmentCode" 
type="EmptySKType"/>
    <xs:element name="OverlapRange" 
type="DateTimeRangeType"/>
    <xs:element name="StartRange" 
  type="DateTimeRangeType"/>
    <xs:element name="StopRange" 
type="DateTimeRangeType"/>
  
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="IncludeDetailSegments" 
default="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
<xs:attribute name="IncludeGeneralSegments" 
default="true" type="xs:boolean"/>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out and if so what was your resolution?